# How to fix image position in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

Whenever I open an image in CS6, it appears right aligned on the screen, and that leaves a lot of unused screen space in the window on left side. This creates problem when ever applying adjustment to the image as I can't see the right portion of the image when adjustment dialog is open.

Is there any way to position the image in Photoshop window left aligned?

From this
[image: How it appears now]

to this
[image: I want to change to this view]

Answer (score 2):

Your palettes on the left hand side appear to be floating. You need to make sure they are fully hard docked to tell Photoshop to rearrange the UI, and exclude that area of the window from the image viewport. By default, Photoshop tries to center the image in the viewport, and if your palettes are not docked properly, then they effectively "float" over the image...causing the problem you are seeing.

When I load up Photoshop, my images center, but do not extend underneath the palettes:

[image]

Comment: :) beautiful shot.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually positioned in the center of the window, but you have toolboxes opening, by default, that obscure the image on that side. Regardless, I don't know of any option in Photoshop to change where the image is opened inside the window, it's always been in the center as far as I remember, which is *way* back to PS4 (pre-CS versions). So, all you can do is control what tools are opened by default.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the palettes are not docked, so the picture is technically centered while it's partly not visible.

Just select the hand tool (H key) and move your image as you wish, clicking and dragging, I think it's the most practical thing to do, particularly if you don't want to change your layout. This is quite handy if you consider display quality in photoshop is pleasant and good enough to judge detail only at "even" display sizes, i.e. 12.5%, 25%, 50%, and obviously 100%, so I usually choose a medium enlargement (e.g. 25% to see most of the picture, this should apply to most cameras with an average Mp count and to most computer screens) and then move the picture around as needed. 
Maybe they fixed this in some recent version of Ps, but it's better anyway to see images at these scaling settings in any software, to avoid being fooled by interpolation artifacts, even though most software does a good joob at hiding such issues.

Maybe you're looking for something different, but your question doesn't seem to imply you'd prefer one kind of approach over another.

More tips: you can nicely handle image magnification and position using the Navigator palette, which anyway I think I see in the screnshots you posted. Also, while using the hand tool, right click anywhere on the picture to set the image to fit the screen or at actual pixels (100%).

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix! In PS, go to WINDOW, then ARRANGE, then "FLOAT IN WINDOW" should take care of it! 
I also set my workspace to photography (WINDOW, WORKSPACE, PHOTOGRAPHY).... Gives you the best layout for editing photographs... Hope this helps!